# Font File Parser with GPos Kerning Table Support for rendering Glyphs

Tags: fonts, freetype, text-rendering, kerning

I am looking for a way to extract glyph bitmaps, glyph metrics and kerning data from font files (.ttf, .otf) with a support for GPos Kerning Tables.

I have used the FreeType Library before, but it does not support GPos Tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using [HarfBuzz](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/HarfBuzz/). This ['hello harfbuzz'](https://github.com/harfbuzz/harfbuzz-tutorial/blob/master/hello-harfbuzz-freetype.c) sample shows how to initialize the library setting it up with a FreeType font. To extract kerning data, I created and shaped a buffer for each combination of letters I supported ('AA', 'AB', etc) and used the positioning data from `hb_buffer_get_glyph_positions` to infer the kerning offsets by comparing it to the advance values from FreeType.